# React: error Module '"react-router-dom"' has no exported member 'useNavigate'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-router

I am trying to import `useNavigate` to use it as described in the top response: [react button onClick redirect page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50644976/react-button-onclick-redirect-page)

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
```

However, I get this error:

```
export 'useNavigate' (imported as 'useNavigate') was not found in 'react-router-dom' (possible exports: BrowserRouter, HashRouter, Link, MemoryRouter, NavLink, Prompt, Redirect, Route, Router, StaticRouter, Switch, generatePath, matchPath, useHistory, useLocation, useParams, useRouteMatch, withRouter)
```

Unlike this post, [export 'useNavigation' (imported as 'useNavigation') was not found in 'react-router-dom'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70703500/export-usenavigation-imported-as-usenavigation-was-not-found-in-react-rou), I spell `useNavigate` correctly, so what could be other reasons as to why there is this error?

Comment: Which version of the router-dom is defined in your package.json ?

Comment: It seems you are not using the latest version (v6) of `react-router-dom`. If you are on RRDv5 import and use the `useHistory` hook, otherwise if you want to use the `useNavigate` hook upgrade to `react-router-dom@6`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is mainly not about how you're importing the `import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";` Its related to how you're using the module. Since you did not show your full code, Here is how you should correctly use the module.

```
    // ️ import useNavigate Here instead of useHistory
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';

export default function WelcomePage() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleClick = () => {
    // Now you can navigate programmatically to other urls
    navigate('/login’);
  };
 // Then create a dom element that will be click to navigate 
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Navigate to login page</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I was facing similar error because I was using the module wrongly as useHistory. But the above is how to use it correctly. You can find a [step by step way of fixing the error here.](https://tutorialscamp.com/react-export-usehistory-was-not-found-in-react-router-dom/)

Answer (score 0):

Probably your installed version is `5`, not `6`.

**Before upgrade**, be aware that moving from `5` to `6` is a painful upgrade: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/docs/upgrading/v5.md

With that in mind, to upgrade it:

Uninstall with `npm uninstall react-router-dom`

And install again `npm install --save react-router-dom`.